# ImportError: No module named 'urllib3'

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, urllib3

Everytime I use pip command the command failed with error: "ImportError: No module named 'urllib3'".
I do got urllib3 installed, and when I'm trying to install urllib3 again I got the same error. What can I do?

I'm using windows 10.

I cant run "pip install virtualenv", I got the same error with any pip command.

Answer (score 2):

May be worth double checking your PYTHONPATH Environment Variable in:
Control Panel\System and Security\System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables.
I had a rogue copy of Python that caused this exact error

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to bootstrap your installation of pip so that you can move along with this.

1. Download the bootstrap script from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
2. Using whatever version of Python you wish, run it, e.g.,

   ```
   C:\\Python35.exe get-pip.py
   ```

After that finishes you should be able to pip install whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

For escaping this error try to install virtualenv through "pip install virtualenv" and create the virtual environment directory using "python3 -m venv myvenv" which will create a myvenv named folder now activate the myvenv folder using "source \myvenv\bin\activate" now you have your virtual environment setup now you can install whatever you want under the venv , which will not conflict with your base os installed programs try some googling to explore pic virtualenv setup and use. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by deinstalling python and reinstall it.

Then you can run

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

to get the latest version of pip